# Compatibility of Generics with legacy code - why does the foreach blow at runtime while iterator works fine

Tags: java, generics, compatibility, legacy-code

I have the following test code.  I'm trying to understand the interoperability between Generics and legacy.

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add("abc");
myList.add(1);
myList.add(new Object());

System.out.println("Printing the unchecked list");
Iterator iterator = myList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(iterator.next());
}

List<String> strings = myList;

System.out.println("Printing the unchecked list assigned to List<String> using iterator");
Iterator stringIterator = strings.iterator();
while (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(stringIterator.next());  // this works fine! why? shouldn't it fail converting the 1 (int/Integer) to String?
}

System.out.println("Printing the unchecked list assigned to List<String> using for");
for (int i = 0; i != strings.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(strings.get(i));  // blows up as expected in the second element, why?
}

System.out.println("Printing the unchecked list assigned to List<String> using foreach");
for (String s : strings) {
  System.out.println(s);  // blows up as expected in the second element, why?
}
```

Why does the `iterator.next` work fine when I try to print it while the `System.out.println` blows up as expected when I iterate using `for` loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to remember about generics is that it's simply a way to omit casts from the source code. The casts are inserted by the compiler. So, code fails (or does not fail) because of the presence (or absence) of a cast.

> 1. this works fine! why?

Because `stringIterator` is raw, `stringIterator.next()` isn't cast to anything: it's just read as an `Object`, which is the erased return type.

> 2. blows up as expected in the second element, why?

`strings` is a `List<String>`, so the result of `strings.get(i)` is assumed to be `String`, and `println(String)` is chosen to be invoked, rather than `println(Object)`. As such, a cast is inserted. `strings.get(1)` isn't a `String`, so this fails with a `ClassCastException`.

Interestingly, had you been trying this with a `List<Integer>`, this wouldn't have failed, because `println(Object)` would be invoked, and no cast would then have been necessary.

> 3. blows up as expected in the second element, why?

Because there's a cast to `String` inserted, to assign the element to `String s`.

Refer to [JLS 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for the desugared form of the enhanced for loop:

> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
>         (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

So, your code is equivalent to:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = strings.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  String s = (String) it.next();  // Actually, your code fails on this line.
  System.out.println(s);
}
```